# Convert Image to Thumbnail and Save

Tags: android, thumbnails, android-bitmap

In my android application I am creating an image using camera, I am using camera API for that, I have to display its thumbnails, after taking the picture, and that I wish to keep in another folder. so my output to the thumbnail creator function would be the image path and I am expecting a file output which is the thumbnail path. I have gone through many tutorials and developer documentation, I have found many methods

```
eg : ThumbnailUtils,..
```

but all these methods returns either Bitmap object or byte arrays, . what is the best way to get save thumnail of an image.

```
public void manageImage() {
    /*
       other things
   */
      Model.addThumnailPath(createThumnail(imageFile));
 }

public String createThumnail(File imageFile){
    // operations

  return thumnailPath;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to search for *how to save a Bitmap to file*.

Comment: is there any other way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best way to create a thumbnail is either use

- [ThumbnailUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html)
- reinvent the wheel and do the steps below
                 
    1. Calculate the maximum possible inSampleSize that still yields an image larger than your target.

    2. Load the image using BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options), passing inSampleSize as an option.

     3. Resize to the desired dimensions using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap().

Now you have your bitmap ready and you can save it any where using the following code

```
Bitmap thumbnail;
File thumbnailFile = ...;
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(thumbnailFile);
thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Thats it :)